# title not populating from content page

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf with spring-mvc to create template in my application. I have created 3 files (head, layout and content) as below;

**head.html**

```
<title>layout<title>
```

**layout.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head th:include="head"></head>
</html>
```

**content.html**

```
<html layout:decorator="layout" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
  <head>
    <title>content</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

---

Now with this setup, when I run my application and open content.html page I see title as "layout" instead of "content".

Am I doing something wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

**Specific answer**

In the layout files title, make the title as `content`

```
<title layout:title-pattern="$CONTENT_TITLE"></title>
```

---

**Further description**

Lets assume the application main title is `"My Web"` and you are viewing the page content with the title `"Content"`

To make the page display the title as `"My Web - Content"`

*Layout File*

```
<title layout:title-pattern="$DECORATOR_TITLE - $CONTENT_TITLE">My Web</title>
```

*ContentFile*

```
<html layout:decorator="layout" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
  <head>
    <title>Content</title>
  </head>
</html>
```